# '$sample stage could not find a non-duplicate - MongoDB Error

Tags: mongodb, pyspark

We are using Spark job to pull the data from MongoDB and performing the Business logic. However at some point of time we are getting the following sporadic error. The job is running fine after restarting it. We are not using any $sample operation in our code.

The full response is

```
{
  "ok": 0,
  "errmsg": "$sample stage could not find a non-duplicate document after 100 while using a random cursor. This is likely a sporadic failure, please try again.",
  "code": 28799,
  "codeName": "Location28799"
}
```

- Spark version : 2.3.0
- Python version : 2.7.5
- MongoDB : 4.0.4
- Pymongo : 2.3.1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Spark connector uses $sample when inferring the schema.

Comment: Joe, do we know why this issue is happening ? and the job is working fine after restarting it

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error as well

What fixed it for me was adding the **samplesPerPartition** option with value 1 in my Spark job

```
.option("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.samplesPerPartition", 1)
```